# Cartopy oceans cover land

Tags: python, cartopy

*Edit*: seems to be a known issue (https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/803#issuecomment-272286945) with certain map projections.

---

For some reason, the NaturalEarth oceans cover the continents, as shown in the example below. If I plot `'physical', 'land'` it behaves as expected (land is filled), but for `'physical', 'ocean'` I would expect the opposite, but instead everything is filled. Does anyone know why this happens, and/or how it is possible to fill only the oceans?

I also tried `ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)`, but then Cartopy crashes (......)

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

projection = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=4.9, central_latitude=52)

ax = pl.subplot(121, projection=projection)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='g'))
ax.set_extent([-8, 17, 42, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax = pl.subplot(122, projection=projection)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='g'))
ax.set_extent([-8, 17, 42, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Seems to be a projection issue; with `PlateCarree()` it works as expected:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

projection = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=4.9, central_latitude=52)

ax = pl.subplot(221, projection=projection)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='g'))
ax.set_extent([-8, 17, 42, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax = pl.subplot(222, projection=projection)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='g'))
ax.set_extent([-8, 17, 42, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())

projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()

ax = pl.subplot(223, projection=projection)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='g'))
ax.set_extent([-8, 17, 42, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax = pl.subplot(224, projection=projection)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='g'))
ax.set_extent([-8, 17, 42, 60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're setting both of them to the same color so now it's just everything filled in as one color (facecolor='g')?

Comment: @lgaud; they are both in different sub-plots, so that shouldn't be the problem.